# How do I see what javascript modifies a particular bit of HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, debugging

When I load a page, there is a style attribute that has been added to the `<body>` tag that is not there in my templates. How do I discover what javascript has modified it?

Just to be clear, the body tag is now:

```
<body class="home page" style="margin-top: -43px;">
```

So the style is not coming from a style sheet. While the template does not include the "style=" bit at all. So I'm pretty sure that some running javascript is modifying the body tag.

I have both Firefox/Firebug and Chrome Inspector available to me. I have tried right clicking on the body tag in "HTML"/"Elements" view and choosing "break on attributes modification" but the change has happened by the time I can do that, and the break point does not survive a page reload.

I'm using Django and jQuery in case that alters the answer.

Comment: Just do a search in *.js or in the souce for the style attributes? (e.g. if it's background color, look for `backgrounColor` or `background-color` within any scripts)

Comment: The "break on attribute modification" *should* survive a page reload.  I just tested this in Chrome.  However,  I don't know that much more about them so can't comment further.

Comment: The breakpoints only kick into gear after you put focus back on the developer console after a page reload.  Weird.  Try putting it on one of the tags on this page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the possibility it is added server side too. If you search your source files for the stylesheet name it should appear in either a JavaScript or a Python file. i.e. grep for "mystylefile.css"

You could disable JavaScript and see if it is still added if you want to narrow it down.

**Update**

Finding what added the margin-top to the element will be harder! You could search your JavaScript files for "margin-top" and see how many results you get back - or add the JavaScript files one by one until one causes it to be added.

Comment: It's been added directly into the HTML rather than into a stylesheet - I'll edit the question to clarify.

Comment: If all else fails, you can add in the JavaScript files one by one until it appears - then you know which file has added it.

Comment: Searching the javascript for "margin-top" eventually turned up the culprit - thanks for reminding me that good old grep (well ack) is my friend.

Answer (score 2):

I currently use an extension of Firebug called **FireDiff** you can file its homepage here: http://www.incaseofstairs.com/firediff/

Answer (score 1):

You could use [mutation observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/MutationObserver).
Try adding this code as the first thing that gets executed on page load:

```
var target = document.querySelector('body'),
    observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
        mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
            debugger;
        });
    });
  
observer.observe(target, { attributes: true });
```

As a side note, it'd be great if that particular kind of breakpoints survived page reload.

Comment: I believe they do in Chrome, but they don't trigger while the page is initially loading it seems.  I have to put focus on the developer panel before it starts working (by clicked on the elements tab, e.g.)